# how to parse json from a url using volly

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, android-volley

With below code i tried to parse json text from a url using Volly. but instead of giving the result it giving the some exception

```
2019-03-21 09:47:29.138 8603-8603/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:57:20.919 8603-8603/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:57:21.522 8603-8603/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:57:25.578 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:57:32.832 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:57:32.879 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:58:09.997 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:58:10.084 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:58:12.130 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:58:12.156 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:58:13.473 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:58:13.508 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:58:16.968 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:58:16.993 21642-21642/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 09:58:33.128 8603-8603/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
2019-03-21 10:02:29.501 8603-8603/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
```

below is the json structure.

```
{"ip":"111.125.204.140","type":"ipv4","continent_code":"AS","continent_name":"Asia"}
```

from above json text i want to fetch type value. below are my code.

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="http://api.ipstack.com/111.125.204.140?access_key=##########";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    JSONObject json = null;
                    try {
                        json = new JSONObject(response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String cityName = json.optString("type");// here iam not getting any value.
                    txtJson.setText(cityName);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            txtJson.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: which line does it gives error , post your full stacktrace

Comment: first check your response is not null.

Comment: You need to include stack trace. Exception message is not enough in that case.

Comment: i edited the question please have a look

Comment: debug and check if you are getting values in your response object.

Comment: not getting any value in response object

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

You got `NullPointerException` because your `json` variable is null at this line:

`String cityName = json.optString("type");`

You need to check that is null or not before you use it.

I think you got an exception when you try to parse the response, but you catch it and simply log it, but you don't handle it.

Comment: Yes i tried catching the response object its not giving any value. But i didnt get what exactly is the issue

Comment: Maybe you got a JSONArray instead of JSONObject?

Comment: then how will i get JSONObject?

Comment: Like how you get an object from an array.